# Uncrush PNG image on ubuntu?

Tags: image, png, ipa, pngcrush

IPA image uses pngcrush to compress PNG image, but I want to uncrush a PNG image on Ubuntu.

Can anyone give me any idea?

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you want? There is no uncrush for PNGs. pngcrush compresses existing PNG images by recompressing it with the highest (and slowest) level of flate compression, but doesn't modify the pixels. Are you asking for a way to expand a PNG file into a flat bitmap?

Answer (score 4):

The standard PNG utility `pngcrush` has been modified by Apple, which makes it produce technically *invalid* PNGs: a new chunk is inserted before the mandatory first chunk `IHDR`, RGB(A) order of pixel data is inverted, and RGB pixels get premultiplied with their alpha.

Hence, I'd rather call these PNGs "fried", rather than just "crushed".

Try my own [`pngdefry`](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html). The source code is written on a Mac OSX machine but it should be compilable for other OSes as well; it's pretty straightforward C code.